# Why does exit /b not work properly when called from Jenkins (but everywhere else)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I've got the following problem: My project has a `make_all.bat` file which executes several builds like this:

```
call make_first_component.bat
if %ERRORLEVEL% gtr 0 ( exit /b %ERRORLEVEL% )

call make_second_component.bat
if %ERRORLEVEL% gtr 0 ( exit /b %ERRORLEVEL% )
```

There are no additional lines in that script (except for `echo` commands).

Now when I call that script manually by double clicking, or from the command line, and make_first_component.bat does something like `exit /b 1`, the `make_all.bat` quits as intended.

When I call the script from a jenkins job (code below), `make_all.bat` continues with the second component even if the first component fails.
If I then log onto the build slave with this behaviour and manually start the batch file there, it quits if the first component fails.

So what does jenkins do that breaks the `%ERRORLEVEL%` concept?

PS: I've tried doing `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and then using `!ERRORLEVEL!`, but it is always 0.

---

Note: The jenkins job has an "Execute Windows batch command" step which looks like this:

```
cd %WORKSPACE%\src\bat

echo Setting up Visual Studio environment
call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

echo Building Project
call make_all.bat
if %ERRORLEVEL% gtr 0 ( exit /b %ERRORLEVEL% )
```

(That is the complete step)

Comment: I suppose the jenkins script is a `*.cmd` file instead of a batch `*.bat`file` ? Mixing .bat and .cmd will produce problems with `%errorlevel%`

Comment: What version of Jenkins are you using?  @jeb Jenkins generates a `.bat` file. Also note that the last line of scripts is `exit %ERRORLEVEL%` and is called by `cmd /c call script.bat`  [BatchFile.java Source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/BatchFile.java)

Comment: Does it still ignores the errorlevel if you place a line `cd thisDoesntExist` just before the errorlevel test? The ERRORLEVEL will fail when it's manually set to a value like `SET ERRORLEVEL=0`

Comment: Could you set `@echo on` in all the scripts and rerun the job and then post the console output?  Just guessing, but the problem may not be with the batch files but user permissions since by default Jenkins runs using the `Local System` user and does not have admin access.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann: the token for local system includes the Administrators group, so for (almost all) purposes it does have admin access.  (But perhaps Jenkins intentionally creates and uses a less privileged token?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect would occur when ERRORLEVEL is overwritten.

Sample

```
set errorlevel=0
cd ThisDoesntExist
echo %errorlevel%
set "errorlevel="
echo %errorlevel%
```

It outputs

> 0
>   1

Conclusion: With `set "errorlevel="` you can restore the normal `%ERRORLEVEL%` behaviour

Comment: Precisely, resetting the error level before calling `make_all.bat` solved it. Thank you :)